# How to use Specs2 with Scalacheck to automate testing of String arguments?

Tags: scala, specs, scalacheck, specs2

The rewritten [specs2](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/) testing framework for Scala integrates automated testing with [scalacheck](http://code.google.com/p/scalacheck/). The examples given in the specs2 documentation on how to use scalacheck together with specs2 either [use integers](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.SpecStructure.html#ScalaCheck+values) or more complicated custom generators as in [eric's json example](http://etorreborre.blogspot.com/2011/02/scalacheck-generator-for-json.html).

While trying to get a slightly less complicated example working, I'm struggling because I don't know how one would use specs2 and scalacheck if I want to generate String arguments instead of Integers. How would this Quickstart example

```
import org.scalacheck._
```

object StringSpecification extends Properties("String") {
  property("startsWith") = Prop.forAll((a: String, b: String) 
     => (a+b).startsWith(a))

property("endsWith") = Prop.forAll((a: String, b: String)
     => (a+b).endsWith(b))

// Is this really always true?
  property("concat") = Prop.forAll((a: String, b: String) => 
    (a+b).length > a.length && (a+b).length > b.length
  )

property("substring") = Prop.forAll((a: String, b: String) => 
    (a+b).substring(a.length) == b
  )

property("substring") = Prop.forAll((a: String, b: String, c: String) =>
    (a+b+c).substring(a.length, a.length+b.length) == b
  )
}

taken from the [scalacheck homepage](http://code.google.com/p/scalacheck/) look, if it was written as Specs2 specification using the scalacheck integration?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A very direct translation is using the `check` method and simple functions:

```
package test

import org.specs2._
import org.scalacheck._

class ScalaCheckExamples extends Specification with ScalaCheck { def is =

  "startsWith" ! check { (a: String, b: String) => (a+b).startsWith(a) }                                                ^
  "endsWith"   ! check { (a: String, b: String) => (a+b).endsWith(b) }                                                  ^
  "concat"     ! check { (a: String, b: String) => (a+b).length > a.length && (a+b).length > b.length }                 ^
  "substring"  ! check { (a: String, b: String) => (a+b).substring(a.length) == b }                                     ^
  "substring"  ! check { (a: String, b: String, c: String) => (a+b+c).substring(a.length, a.length+b.length) == b }     ^
                                                                                                                        end
 }
```

And the output actually shows that the `concat` property is not correct:

```
  [info] + startsWith
  [info] + endsWith
  [error] x concat
  [error]   A counter-example is ['', ''] (after 0 try)
  [error] the value is false
  [error]  (ScalaCheckExamplesSpec.scala:6)
  [info] + substring
  [info] + substring
  [info]
  [info] Total for specification ScalaCheckExamplesSpec
  [info] Finished in 7 seconds, 547 ms
  [info] 5 examples, 401 expectations, 1 failure, 0 error
  [info]
```

Eric.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This really clarified some things for me. Maybe you want consider adding this example into the example code tree?

Answer (score 2):

For more information on using the ScalaCheck library in specs2, check out the [ScalaCheck Guide in the specs2 documentation](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-4.10.0/org.specs2.guide.UseScalaCheck.html).

Comment: I got an HTTP 404 for the above site.

Comment: @KevinMeredith Try this https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.9.1/org.specs2.guide.UseScalaCheck.html